# How to make work of ajax on rails forms and how to get validation errors from server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, validation, model, ujs

I am trying to apply [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example) rails tutorial to my project. I made create action works. I added some validation to my model file.
Now, problem comes here. When i submit entry form, rails must give errors. In the normal html way i can see the errors. But this ajax style page i can't make it work.

When i'am sending empty form, i can't get full_message validation error.

[image]

**My error on console**

```
Started POST "/personels" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-02-05 11:38:18 +0300
Processing by PersonelsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"79VVfQ99zFbghWb7jMgjJzYb021qIeAQwte/XPCdSAEWF+SiC9gD11i4ZMoTJayPf+oZlJZplt6w8AwDmZ1+6g==", "personel"=>{"name"=>"", "surname"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Personel"}
  Rendering personels/create.js.erb
  Rendered personels/_personel.html.erb (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 1061)
  Rendered personels/create.js.erb (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 1136)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2760)


  
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"personels", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]):
    2:         <td><%= personel.name %></td>
    3:         <td><%= personel.surname %></td>
    4:         <td><%= link_to 'Show', personel %></td>
    5:         <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_personel_path(personel) %></td>
    6:         <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', personel, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    7: </tr>
  
app/views/personels/_personel.html.erb:5
app/views/personels/create.js.erb:2
app/controllers/personels_controller.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in create'
app/controllers/personels_controller.rb:33:in `create'
```

**I am not editing record but it seems to trying to go :action => "edit". I don't understand why it is like happens.**

**Personel Controller**

```
def create
    @personel = Personel.new(personel_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @personel.save
        format.html { redirect_to @personels, notice: 'Personel was successfully created.' }
        format.js
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @personel }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.js   { render layout: false , personel: @personel}
        format.json { render json: @personel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Personel Model**

```
class Personel < ApplicationRecord
validates :name, :surname, presence: true
  belongs_to :journal_doc_analytic, optional: true

  def name_with_initial
    "#{name} - #{surname}"
  end
end
```

**create.js.erb file**

```
var personels = document.querySelector("#personels");
personels.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<%= j render(@personel) %>");

var personel_name = document.querySelector("#personel_name");
personel_name.value = ""

var personel_surname = document.querySelector("#personel_surname");
personel_surname.value = ""

var notice = document.querySelector("#notice");
notice.innerText = "Personel was successfully created."

setTimeout(function(){
  notice.innerText = "";
}, 2500);
```

**_personel.html partial**

```
<tr>
        <td><%= personel.name %></td>
        <td><%= personel.surname %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', personel %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_personel_path(personel) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', personel, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

**index.html.erb of Personel**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= render 'form', personel: @personel %>
<h1>Personels</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

<tbody id="personels">
<%= render @personels %>
</tbody>
<br>
<%= link_to 'ORDER', personels_path(order: :asc) %>
<%= link_to 'ORDER desc', personels_path(order: :desc) %>
```

**_form.html.erb Partial**

**Espacially i added this script to code below :**
ERROR <%= personel.errors.full_messages.first %>

```
<script>window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const element = document.querySelector("#new-personel");
  element.addEventListener("ajax:success", (event) => {
    const [_data, _status, xhr] = event.detail;
    element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", xhr.responseText);
  });
  element.addEventListener("ajax:error", () => {
    element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>ERROR <%= personel.errors.full_messages.first %></p>");
  });
});</script>

<%= form_with(model: personel, id: "new-personel", local: false) do |form| %>
  <% if personel.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(personel.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this personel from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% personel.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :surname %>
    <%= form.text_field :surname %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit data: {disable_with: "Saving..."} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
personels GET    /personels(.:format)                                                                     personels#index
                                      POST   /personels(.:format)                                                                     personels#create
                         new_personel GET    /personels/new(.:format)                                                                 personels#new
                        edit_personel GET    /personels/:id/edit(.:format)                                                            personels#edit
                             personel GET    /personels/:id(.:format)                                                                 personels#show
                                      PATCH  /personels/:id(.:format)                                                                 personels#update
                                      PUT    /personels/:id(.:format)                                                                 personels#update
                                      DELETE /personels/:id(.:format)                                                                 personels#destroy
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your routes. Since it's trying to route a POST request to `personels#edit`, which doesn't exist. Can you add your routes to this example as well?

Comment: Actually server sends empty Personel object. Then _personel.html.erb partial trying to populate personel which is empty.

Comment: That's not what your error is about. What is the data that is sent by the Ajax request? Maybe it sends an id, which makes rails interpret it as an update instead of trying to create a new Personel object.

Comment: You should not have a `format.js` if `@personel.save` has failed. At the moment you try to append the newly created record to your view in case it has been created AND in case it hasn't been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I added new partial is named:

** _error.html.erb **

```
<% if @personel.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@personel.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this personel from 
being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
    <% @personel.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and updated my ** create.js.erb **

```
var errors = document.querySelector("#errors");
errors.replaceChildren("");

if (errors.childElementCount == 0){ 
errors.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<%= j render partial: '/personels/error' %>");
var notice = document.querySelector("#notice");
notice.innerText = "";
} else {
var notice = document.querySelector("#notice");
notice.innerText = "Personel was successfully created.";
}

var personels = document.querySelector("#personels");
personels.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<%= j render(@personel) %>");

var personel_name = document.querySelector("#personel_name");
personel_name.value = ""

var personel_surname = document.querySelector("#personel_surname");
personel_surname.value = ""

setTimeout(function(){
notice.innerText = "";
}, 2500);
```

Result is :
[image]

My controller is same.